# GORM Preload by condition in a related table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I can't figure how to properly write a query that will select only those entries where condition is applied against relations table.
My many-to-many schema looks like this `Topics` - `TopicPosts` - `Posts`. I want to query all `TopicPosts` where `Post` is not private or is belongs to the current user. I'm doing it like this:

```
topicPosts := []model.TopicPost{}
h.DB.
    Where("topic_id = ?", id).
    Preload("Post", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Not("is_private = ? AND user_id != ?", "true", currentUser.ID)
    }).
    Preload("Post.Tags").
    Find(&topicPosts)
```

As expected it returns all `TopicPosts` but does not eagerly load `Posts` with a given condition. I then manually filter them out:

```
publicTopicPosts := []model.TopicPost{}
for _, p := range topicPosts {
    if p.Post.ID != 0 {
        publicTopicPosts = append(publicTopicPosts, p)
    }
}
```

I realise this is a subpar solution, I'm not very good with SQL but I think it should be possible to achieve within a single query. I would appreciate any help. I'm using Postgres if it matters.

Comment: What about calling `h.DB.Debug().Where ...` before you run the query to see what SQL is being executed?

Comment: Also, you may have done this and not shown it for brevity, but be sure to check the `.Error` field when you have run a query, to know you can trust the contents of what you have loaded. `err := h.DB.Where()....Find(&dest).Error`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this method

```
db.Preload("Post", "is_private = ? AND user_id != ?", "true", currentUser.ID).Find(&topicPosts)
```

Comment: But what is `SubQuery()` ? I cannot trace it anywhere in gorm.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience the most appropriate way to do that with GORM is by utilizing SubQueries:

```
topicPosts := []model.TopicPost{}   

DB.GetDB().
    Where("topic_id = ? AND post_id IN (?)", id,
        DB.GetDB().Table("posts").
            Select("id").
            Not("is_private = ? AND user_id != ?", "true", currentUser.ID)).
            SubQuery()).

    Preload("Post").
    Find(&topicPosts)
```